# Segmentation fault: 11 with ConvexHull method of scipy.Spatial

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scipy-spatial

I am trying out https://github.com/alievk/avatarify in my Mac OS X and when I try executing the program after all the installation steps, I face the following error.

`run_mac.sh: line 11: 80178 Segmentation fault: 11  python cam_fomm.py --config $CONFIG --checkpoint $CKPT --cam $CAMID --relative --adapt_scale --no-pad`

I was able to isolate the cause of the issue to the ConvexHull method from scipy.Spatial package used. But not sure how to fix the issue.

Comment: Possibly related issue:https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9751

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes. It seems to be the case. The others facing the issue are having the same OS version and XCode version I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post all the steps you took, and what the convex hull error is? The convex hull algorithm in scipy.spatial (Qhull Algorithm) raises exceptions in multiple scenarios. Qhull expects points to be well behaved in 2D. For example if all the points fed to it are the same point, it will raise an exception:

```
>>> from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
>>> import numpy as np
>>> points = np.zeros((30,2))
>>> hull = ConvexHull(points)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "qhull.pyx", line 2359, in scipy.spatial.qhull.ConvexHull.__init__
  File "qhull.pyx", line 354, in scipy.spatial.qhull._Qhull.__init__
scipy.spatial.qhull.QhullError: QH6013 qhull input error: input is less than 2-dimensional since it has the same x coordinate

While executing:  | qhull i Qt
Options selected for Qhull 2015.2.r 2016/01/18:
  run-id 567167702  incidence  Qtriangulate  _pre-merge  _zero-centrum
  _max-width  0  Error-roundoff  0  _one-merge  0  _near-inside  0
  Visible-distance  0  U-coplanar-distance  0  Width-outside  0  _wide-facet  0
```

One way to debug your problem would be to print out the input points, before invoking the ConvexHull algorithm, and then look at the traceback that ConveHull raises, on those input points. That should help in narrowing down the problem.

Comment: I am trying to execute the program from https://github.com/alievk/avatarify. So, I am not fully quite sure how to debug further on this. The logs statements did not provide much insight so I added few debug statements and the best I could do was find the source of the error. I'm sorry about not being able to provide more details here.

Comment: def normalize_alignment_kp(kp):
    kp = kp - kp.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True)
    log('Got mean')
    log(kp)
    area = ConvexHull(kp[:, :2]).volume
    log('Got area')
    area = np.sqrt(area)
    log('Got sqrt')
    kp[:, :2] = kp[:, :2] / area
    return kp
Above is the code snippet where this is being called. I have tried printing the values but still not sure what to do about them.